# CodePlex Alternative of Caliburn Micro Reference Implementation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

This stack overflow post shares a CodePlex URL for Caliburn Micro reference implementations [Caliburn Micro reference implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319902/caliburn-micro-reference-implementations/54881725#54881725).

However since CodePlex is no is no longer available, can some one help with an alternative where those reference implementations could be found...

Comment: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples contains some samples that might be helpful enough?